# How can I record a transition from a 0 to 1 in a column in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to record the number of transitions from a down state (0) to up state (1) in a single column in excel and I am wondering whether there is some kind of logic like this available in Excel or whether I can program this kind of logic in VBA. I am not very well versed in VBA however, so if any links are available, that would be great. Thank you guys for all your help!

Comment: how your data organised?

Comment: Not full solution, but think might help to think of it as two problems. One is just to detect that a change of some type has happened. After that it should be easy to tell if the value is now zero or one, maybe needing to save prior value for compare. For detecting the change take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I don't think you need a VB script (macro) to do this. Simple Excel functions should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the **Sumproduct()** worksheet function:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Exactly what I was looking for, and I will look into the SUMPRODUCT function to see how it works for more detail. However, this doesn't take into consideration if the column already begins in a 1, is there any way to add this extra logic? I am currently looking into this, and would appreciate any help. Thanks again.

Comment: If your data begins at **A1** and you want to consider an initial **1** as part of your record then  *=A1+SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A9=0)*(A2:A10=1))*

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Foo()

No_of_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
temp = 0
For i = 1 To No_of_rows
If Cells(i, 1) = 0 And Cells(i + 1, 1) = 1 Then
temp = temp + 1
End If

Next
Cells(1, 2) = temp

End Sub
```

Result would be in B1

Answer (score 0):

The following nested Excel expression

```
=IF(AND(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1)=0,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),1,-1)=1), 1, 0)
```

Sets a cell value to 1, if the value of a cell is 0 AND cell under it is 1.

```
0   0
0   0
0   1  <-- Transition
1   0
1   0
1   0
0   0
0   1  <-- Transition
1   0
0   0
0   0
```

I have to agree that the selected answer is much cleaner than this, but this is an alternative if marking the transition is important.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work.
Paste the code in the VBE in the workbook

```
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim rngCell As Range

'Define Range on spreadsheet, Range A1:A13 in this example
Set rngTemp = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(13, 1))

'Clear Counter
lngCount = 0

'Loop through range and count the changes while ignoring the first row
For Each rngCell In rngTemp
    If rngCell.Row <> 1 Then
        If rngCell.Value = 1 And rngCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = 0 Then
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell

MsgBox "There are " & lngCount & " transitions"
```

Comment: This counts all transitions, the OP is looking for 0 to 1 transitions.